# Gmail search API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-api

I am making an Ionic application with GMail sign-in, using Firebase. I am able to sign in the user and get the user ID and other profile details. I want to access the raw GMail message body to find particular emails coming from specific sender.

I referred to the documentation, but I am facing an issue with `gapi.client`. I am getting the error:

> gapi.client.error userId path is not defined

How can I fix this error and retrieve messages from the user's GMail account?

Comment: Please include the relevant line of code that raises the error, and what you think the error might mean. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more tips.

Comment: message: "Required path parameter userId is missing."
stack:"gapi.client.Error↵    at new wY (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.YNLsGUztfc4.O/m=client,plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCME_DdvLwJqaGCF1tFBCiYLDx386g/cb=gapi.loaded_0:572:28)

Comment: Edit your question to include that information, as well as the other information I suggested. Currently your question does not have much information, so it's unlikely to attract answers. *Please* read the guidelines for [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).